# sqlLite in android didnt insert my data to table

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sql-insert

I dont know why i have return result = -1 after execute insertGasData. In other similiar structure the result was != -1, but there is = -1.
There is DatabaseHelper class and main class

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "car.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME2 = "car_gas_table";

    public static final String COL_G_1 = "GAS_ID";
    public static final String COL_G_2 = "GAS_DATE";
    public static final String COL_G_3 = "GAS_MILEAGE";
    public static final String COL_G_4 = "FUEL_TYPE";
    public static final String COL_G_5 = "FUEL_COST";
    public static final String COL_G_6 = "FUEL_VOLUME";
   
    public DatabaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME2 + " (GAS_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, GAS_DATE TEXT, GAS_MILEAGE TEXT, FUEL_TYPE TEXT, FUEL_COST TEXT, FUEL_VOLUME TEXT)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME2);
    }
    
    public boolean insertGasData(String date, String mileage, String fuel_type, String fuel_price, String fuel_volume) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_G_2, date);
        contentValues.put(COL_G_3, mileage);
        contentValues.put(COL_G_4, fuel_type);
        contentValues.put(COL_G_5, fuel_price);
        contentValues.put(COL_G_6, fuel_volume);
        long result = sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME2, null, contentValues);
        if (result == -1)
            return false;
        else return true;
    }
```

there is a call method
i use there Strings to eliminate other mistakes but it doesnt help

```
    public void AddRefuelrData() {
        bDodaj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
             //   boolean isInsert = myDb.insertGasData(eRefDate.getText().toString(), eRefMileage.getText().toString(), eRefType.getText().toString(), eRefPrice.getText().toString(), eRefVolume.getText().toString());
                boolean isInsert = myDb.insertGasData("dd","mm", "tt", "pr", "vo");
                if (isInsert == true)
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data not inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

after call method insertGasData i have return false

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DEgs.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the table is actually created properly?
Use Device File Explorer to check if the database is created or not.
that should help with narrowing down the problem.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I looked for database in Device File Explorer and i deleted database and database-jurnal files. Now works exactly as I wanted

Comment: I'm glad I could help. :)